# Hide All/Grand Total Row and Column From Kendo UI PivotGrid

Tags: kendo-ui

I am currently working with a Kendo UI PivotGrid.  I ran into an issue where I do not want to display the "All" column.  This is the Grand Total column that contains some aggregates of the data in your grid.  The screenshot shows only the "All" column but there is another additional row at the very bottom with aggregate data.  In code it is referred to as "measures" of the grid.  I do not want to view these summations but when I remove the "aggregate" property from the measures the grid does not populate.  Does anyone know of a way to hide this aggregate column and row?  Here is the JavaScript code that I am using to initialize this grid as well as a screenshot:

```
            var pivotgrid = $(divid).kendoPivotGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: result,
                schema: {
                    cube: {
                        measures: { "Data": { field: "Data", format: "{0:n6}", aggregate: "sum" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                columns: [{ name: "Date", expand: true }],
                rows: [{ name: "AcctCd", expand: true }],
                measures: ["Data"]
            }
        }).data("kendoPivotGrid");
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's pretty tough to do this.  Here are two replies from Telerik that say that the pivotGrid is designed to always have the total column.  The first article says that the only workaround for this is to manually remove html elements in the databound event.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-remove-all-elements-in-a-pivotgrid
http://www.telerik.com/forums/hide-totals